# Conntrack on single interface - is it possible?

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables

I want to use conntrack to track per-connection bytes, packets etc. on an end-host with a single network interface, rather than connections through a router with multiple interfaces. That means I will track only connections which terminate on the host.

I have set up conntrack on multiple linux distributions, and the answer to conntrack -L is always the same: "0 flow entries have been shown".

Is there any way of tracking per-connection stats in this way using with conntrack or something else on a Linux end-host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conntrack will be the best way as it stores tuple for each connection. Moreover load the necessary conntrack module in `/lib/modules/xxx/kernel/net/netfilter/yyy.ko` and `/lib/modules/kernel/xxx/net/ipv4/netfilter/yyyy.ko` Though you want connection as you PC as end point Conntrack tool will work if the necessary conntrack module is installed.

Another approach will be write a kernel module and hook it at PRE-ROUTING as you want to catch as end-point and parse the skbs to fullfill you requirements.

Comment: Many thanks Kalu, I've no experience of loading kernel modules, but following research I've added "nf_conntrack" to /etc/modules and ran depmod. Following a reboot, lsmod now shows: 

Module                  Size  Used by

nf_conntrack_netlink    36864  0

nfnetlink              16384  1 nf_conntrack_netlink

However, when I "sudo run conntrack -L" it still shows zero flows after I open a web browser and pull a page. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorted now, thanks - I had forgotten to add second set of modules you mentioned. Summary is:
1. sudo apt-get install conntrack

2. Add the following to /etc/modules:
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv6

3. Run depmod

4. Reboot
Many thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but I can't found nf_conntrack_ipv4 nor nf_conntrack_ipv6 modules. It seems they don't exists on stock Fedora 31 kernel. :-(